# SQL with condition on calculated value

Tags: mysql, group-by, conditional-statements

I have a table with products, their amount and their price. I need to select all entries where the average price per article is between a range.
My query so far:

```
SELECT productid,AVG(SUM(price)/SUM(amount)) AS avg 
FROM stock WHERE avg>=$from AND avg<=$to GROUP BY productid
```

If do this, it tells me avg doesn't exist.
Also I obviously need to group by because the sum and average need to be per wine

Comment: What are you trying to do here? `AVG(SUM(price)/SUM(amount)) `

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to put it in the `HAVING` clause. You cannot filter by the result of aggregates using `WHERE`.

MySQL does allow you to reference column aliases in `HAVING`. You might need

```
SELECT 
      productid,
      AVG(price/amount) AS avg ,
      /*SUM(price)/SUM(amount) AS avg (<--- Or perhaps this?)*/
FROM stock 
GROUP BY productid
HAVING avg>=$from AND avg<=$to
```

But I'm not sure exactly what you are trying to do with `AVG(SUM(price)/SUM(amount))` can you show some example data?